# Making a curl header optional in a bash function

Tags: bash, curl, apache-pulsar

I have a function to upload a topic in Apache Pulsar, but some of my schemas do not fir the the `Content-type` of `json`. Can I still keep this function by somehow setting a header to be optional? Specifically the `--header 'Content-Type: application/json'`

```bash
function uploading_topic {
    echo -e "\n\n+++ Uploading $TOPIC +++"
    curl --location --request POST "https://$PULSAR_HOST:$HOST_PULSAR_PORT/admin/v2/schemas/$TENANT/$NAMESPACE/$TOPIC/schema" \
        --verbose \
        --header "Authorization: Bearer $AUTHORIZATION"  \
        --insecure \
        --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
        --data-raw $SCHEMA 2>&1 | cat | grep "HTTP" # grep -v "Authorization"
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a variable to hold the content type? Then use `--header "Content-type: $type"`

Comment: The `| cat |` looks redundant, turn that into `|`

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. Is having a blank "Content-type" acceptable?

Comment: @Erwin you mean `2>&1 | cat | grep "HTTP"` into just `2>&1 | grep "HTTP"`

Comment: Right. As it is, the `cat` command is just relaying stdin to stdout, which doesn't add anything to the process.

Comment: @Erwin Thanks for that, I'll update with that improvement.

Comment: @Barmar I think you answer is satisfactory, I should have thought of that myself (d'oh!). Do you want to post that as a response and I'll accept the answer?

Comment: I suspect an empty content-type is not technically allowed, but I'd expect servers to treat it the same as no header at all.